# Splitting list of python dictionaries by repeating dictionary key values

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, split

say I have a list of dictionaries:

```
foo = [
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test', 'table': 'partners'},
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test', 'table': 'users'},
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test', 'table': 'sales'},
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new', 'table': 'partners'},
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new', 'table': 'users'},
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new', 'table': 'sales'},
]
```

How can I split this list into separate lists (or into a list of lists) where 'host' **and** 'db_name' are the same?
For example:

```
list1 = [
        {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test', 'table': 'partners'},
        {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test', 'table': 'users'},
        {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test', 'table': 'sales'},
]

list2 = [
        {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new', 'table': 'partners'},
        {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new', 'table': 'users'},
        {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new', 'table': 'sales'},
]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dd = defaultdict(list)
>>> foo = [
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test', 'table': 'partners'},
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test', 'table': 'users'},
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test', 'table': 'sales'},
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new', 'table': 'partners'},
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new', 'table': 'users'},
      {'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new', 'table': 'sales'},
]
>>> for d in foo:
        dd[(d['host'], d['db_name'])].append(d)
```

The lists of lists is the dictionary's values

```
>>> dd.values()
[[{'table': 'partners', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new'}, {'table': 'users', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new'}, {'table': 'sales', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new'}], [{'table': 'partners', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test'}, {'table': 'users', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test'}, {'table': 'sales', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test'}]]
```

Comment: Takes into account host+db name requirement.

Comment: +1 I missed the fact that both host and db_name are required.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect use case for the `groupby` function from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby

foo.sort(key = lambda x: (x['db_name'], x['host']))
it = groupby(foo, key = lambda x: (x['db_name'], x['host']) )

groups = []
keys = []
for k, g in it:
    groups.append(list(g))
    keys.append(k)

print groups
## >>>
##[
##    [{'table': 'partners', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test'},
##     {'table': 'users', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test'},
##     {'table': 'sales', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test'}],
##    [{'table': 'partners', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new'},
##     {'table': 'users', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new'},
##     {'table': 'sales', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new'}]
##]

##or make a dict
d = dict(zip(keys, groups))
```

Comment: Only if you sort before grouping (or maybe they are guaranteed to be sorted?). Otherwise `defaultdict` is a better fit here

Comment: @qwwqwwq it isn't *perfect* since the data is not already sorted so this is `O(n log n)` as opposed to `O(n)` for `defaultdict`

Comment: yes that is true, I added the sorting step above, I was assuming sorted but it is not explicitly stated. Even with sorting I prefer this because for the use case I'm imagining we could altogether avoid making a new data structure, working elegantly on the current data structure as we go through the groupby iterable

Comment: @qwwqwwq A nicer way of doing this would be through `operator.itemgetter` eg. `foo.sort(key=itemgetter('db_name', 'host'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
sp={}
for d in foo:
    sp.setdefault((d['host'],d['db_name']),[]).append(d)
```

Then print it:

```
for l in sp.values():
    for d in l:
        print d
    print     


{'table': 'partners', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new'}
{'table': 'users', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new'}
{'table': 'sales', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'new'}

{'table': 'partners', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test'}
{'table': 'users', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test'}
{'table': 'sales', 'host': 'localhost', 'db_name': 'test'}
```